# using an element from an array of element collection in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The value of u and v are coming correctly as 1 and 0... but the values are not being used in the statement "`t[i].children[v].onclick=function(){}`" ..!!
This works perfectly when I used 1 in the place of u and 0 in the place of v!!!
Here is the code :

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="menu-toggler">Menu</span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>First Part</li>
    <li>Second Part</li>
    </ul>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

function init()
{
    t = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
    for(i=0;i<t.length;i++)
    {
        v = getMenuToggler(t[i]); // v is becoming 0 correctly
        u = getDropDown(t[i]); // u is becoming 1 correctly
 // the next statement is not working properly!!!
        t[i].children[v].onclick=function(){if(this.parentNode.children[u].classList.contains("menu-

open")){this.parentNode.children[u].classList.remove("menu-open");}else{this.parentNode.children

[u].classList.add("menu-open");}}
    }
}

function getDropDown(x) // this function is all right... u can ignore this
{
    for(i=0;i<x.childElementCount;i++)
    {
        if(x.children[i].classList.contains("dropdown-menu"))
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function getMenuToggler(y) //this function is all right... u can ignore this
{
    for(i=0;i<y.childElementCount;i++)
    {
        if(y.children[i].classList.contains("menu-toggler"))
        return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
</script>
<script>window.onload=init;</script>
```

thank you in advance... :)

Comment: shouldn't the class be defined for the <ul> tag?

Comment: nope @goelakash ...cuz thats y i added the t[i].children[0] .... :) so u don't need the class for <ul>

Comment: @vihan1086 `childNodes` will also get Text nodes. Bad idea.

Comment: @vihan1086 tried already... but its even worse... it gets all the text and comment nodes...

Comment: Have you read about the infamous '[closures within loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)' problem?

Comment: `init` shouldn't be called as a function. Then it is called immediately and `window.onload`'s value is set to what `init` returns. It doesn't return anything. Also, because it's called before `onload`, it is called before any of the elements are defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload=init();
```

If you write it like this then `init` is immediately called instead of the function assigned as an event listener.

What you want is:

```
window.onload=init;
```

Or in a more standardized and modern way:

```
window.addEventListener('load',init);
```

If you call `init` too early by mistake like in your original code then the DOM hasn’t loaded yet so you can’t get any elements.

Now in your assigned function to the `onclick` property `t[i]` won’t be defined when you write `t[i].children[1]`.

Because the function is assigned to the `onclick` property of `t[i].children[0]` you can replace `t[i].children[1]` by `this.parentNode.children[1]` which will be equivalent.

Comment: thank you.. but I have tried that too.... the result is the same!!! error : Cannot read property 'children' of undefined.

Comment: and heres what... if I do not use the loop and instead just use : t[0].children[0].onclick=function(){t[i].children[1].classList.add("menu-open");} ... it works beautifully.... but I want to do it using an array!!! bcoz later on i might want to add more elements with class="dropdown"  ....

Comment: For me the `onclick` part works fine but the assigned function brings some issues as `t[i]` won’t be defined within that function. I’ll edit my answer for a possible fix.

Comment: Also `t[i]` is not defined because in your `for` loop you have set `i` as a global variable. At the end of each iteration the third statement in the `for` head — `i++` — executes. After the loop executes for the last time, `i` is incremented one last time. An access to `t[i]` will essentially lead to an index in `t` that exceeds the maximum index by one.

Comment: it works flawlessly.... thank you once again.... the this.parentNode.children[0] does it!!!! :) thank you

Comment: Yeah, I had to edit it again… it should be `this.parentNode.children[1]`, right? I accidentally left the wrong index number in there…

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown" onclick="add_class(this)">
    <span>Menu</span>
    <ul>
        <li>First Part</li>
        <li>Second Part</li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <script>

    function add_class(dropdown) {
      dropdown.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].className = (dropdown.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].className == "menu-open") ? "" : "menu-open";
   }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 1 flaws in your code

1. you are not calling the function from anywhere , it is just
   declared, so i called from ul when clicked .

   - so there is no need to call this line t[i].onclick ,
   - my code is adding class **menu-open** to the element ul.

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/yosrknv3/1/

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <span>Menu</span>
        <ul onclick="init_menu()">
            <li >First Part</li>
            <li>Second Part</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<script>
    function init_menu()
    {
            t=document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");                                for(i=0;i<t.length;i++)
            {
                 console.log("i am clicked"+t[i],t[i].children[1]);
                 t[i].children[1].classList.add("menu-open");
            }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Shelly but i knew that adding onclick="init_menu()" would do it... :) but i actually wanted it to get ready for clicking as soon as the page loaded.... replacing with this.parentNode.children[1] does the trick... :) thanks